# DirectX Invalid Call when ResizeBuffers

Tags: c#, directx, slimdx

I'm writing a very simple modeling software, more as a challenge than anything else.
Up to about 3 weeks ago, I had no real problem with the SwapChain.ResizeBuffers() function.

I changed of PC, switched to Visual Studio Express 2012 (from Pro 9), and switch my solution to x64 with the corresponding SlimDX.dll.

It still runs fine, but when I resize my window hosting the viewport, it get : DXGI_ERROR_INVALID_CALL (-2005270527).

A quick search on google tells me Battlefield 3 also may have that problem with some specific drivers. Is it possible?

I've read everything I could find about that function, and somehow I can't find what changes that is now messing things up. Hopefully, someone can see what I'm doing wrong.

```
    // Form we are attached to.
    private Dockable dock;

    // Rendering stuff.
    private Device device;
    private Viewport viewport;
    private SwapChain swapChain;
    private RenderTargetView renderView;
    private DepthStencilView depthView;

    public Renderer(Dockable form)
    {
        if (form == null)
            return;

        dock = form;

        CreateSwapchain();
        Resize();
    }

    private void CreateSwapchain()
    {
        // Swap Chain & Device
        SwapChainDescription description = new SwapChainDescription()
        {
            BufferCount = 1,
            Usage = Usage.RenderTargetOutput,
            OutputHandle = dock.Handle,
            IsWindowed = true,
            ModeDescription = new ModeDescription(dock.ClientSize.Width, dock.ClientSize.Height, new Rational(60, 1), Format.R8G8B8A8_UNorm),
            SampleDescription = new SampleDescription(1, 0),
            Flags = SwapChainFlags.AllowModeSwitch,
            SwapEffect = SwapEffect.Discard
        };

        Device.CreateWithSwapChain(DriverType.Hardware, DeviceCreationFlags.Debug, description, out device, out swapChain);
    }

    private void CreateRenderView()
    {
        // Dispose before resizing.
        if (renderView != null)
            renderView.Dispose();

        if (depthView != null)
            depthView.Dispose();

        swapChain.ResizeBuffers(0, 0, 0, Format.Unknown, 0); // ERROR : DXGI_ERROR_INVALID_CALL when resizing the window, but not when creating it.
        renderView = new RenderTargetView(device, Resource.FromSwapChain<Texture2D>(swapChain, 0));

        Texture2DDescription depthBufferDesc = new Texture2DDescription()
        {
            ArraySize = 1,
            BindFlags = BindFlags.DepthStencil,
            CpuAccessFlags = CpuAccessFlags.None,
            Format = Format.D16_UNorm,
            Height = dock.ClientSize.Height,
            Width = dock.ClientSize.Width,
            MipLevels = 1,
            OptionFlags = ResourceOptionFlags.None,
            SampleDescription = new SampleDescription(1, 0),
            Usage = ResourceUsage.Default
        };

        depthView = new DepthStencilView(device, new Texture2D(device, depthBufferDesc));
    }

    public void Resize()
    {
        CreateRenderView();

        viewport = new Viewport(0.0f, 0.0f, dock.ClientSize.Width, dock.ClientSize.Height);
        device.ImmediateContext.Rasterizer.SetViewports(viewport);
        device.ImmediateContext.OutputMerger.SetTargets(depthView, renderView);
    }
```

Comment: I am going to guess the problem has something to do with the SlimDX.dll contact the author for assistance.  I would suggest only using the Microsoft library, it would seem the library you are trying to use, has a critical bug in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to release all resources associated to your swap chain before to resize it.

So that includes the render view (which you do), but you do addref on the resource when you create your render target view.

```
Resource.FromSwapChain<Texture2D>(swapChain, 0)
```

Adds a ref counter to the texture. Since you don't cache it, you can't release it.

So you need to do:

```
Texture2D resource = Texture2D.FromSwapChain<Texture2D>(swapChain, 0);
renderView = new RenderTargetView(device, resource);
```

then before to call resize:

```
if (resource != null) { resource.Dispose(); }
```

Just tested it on my engine and it works (also you were right with 0s, it works too).

Comment: When a SwapChain is linked to a window handle, the ResizeBuffers method is able to pull that information directly, it doesn't require you to supply it. That implementation of ResizeBuffers, as written like that (and as explained in DirectX doc), ask the SwapChain to resize, but doesn't change any other params. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174577%28v=vs.85%29.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205075%28v=vs.85%29.aspx Just saying, because it's something I already tried, but every doc from Microsoft implement it that way.

Comment: @Marc-AndréJutras : You were right for zeroes, problem was from resource release, updated answer.

Comment: Also, as specified on remarks here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174577(v=vs.85).aspx, make sure that resources of views related to your swapchain are not bound to device context.

Comment: You can and should release the Texture2D resource immediately after you create the RenderTargetView since you're not using it either way. The issue here is that the COM reference isn't decremented automatically when the .Net object is collected. The actual buffer is then only referenced by the RTV and will be automagically released when you release the RTV in CreateRenderView.